.htaccess redirect all pages to the homepage on a new domain for Wordpress application hosted in ions
I have domain hosted in ionos for my Wordpress site. I want to redirect the all the pages of old domain to new domain main page. With the rewrite rule in .htaccess , https://old-domain redirects to https://new-domain/en successfully.
However, any extensions to the site url, does not redirect.
for instance, https://old-domain.com/location1/en to https://new-domain/en
I added
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

however, the links are being added to new domain.
https://old-domain.com/location1/en to https://new-domain/en/location1/en
I followed this link and tried different ways as mentioned.
still not working. please help me to resolve this.
Note: I see the /%category%/%postname%/ has been set in Custom Structure in Settings of Wordpress.

"however, the links are being added to new domain." - of course, that's what the $1 part in your substitution URL does - it inserts what ^(.*)$ captured, which will be the full request path. So leave out the $1 then, if you want everything redirect to the root of the new domain.

What you state in the question contradicts itself in a few points. It is hard to understand what exactly is your issue, what redirection is actually implemented and how it works precisely . Based on such vague information it is hard to answer a question. I suggest you take a bit of time to revise your question (there is an "edit" link below it) to rephrase your statements such that they are precise . Does redirection add a "en" or not? If so, where does that come from? Does the current redirection really omit the "location1"? What exactly is a "link" in this?
